# Can't create tables in postgresql

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework, pgadmin

I manually deleted two tables in pgAdmin and now I want to create it again.
I made some changes, applyed migrations but this tables was not created.
Can't understand, why?

When I send request to add item to this tables, I'm getting error: *relation "ProductsComparsion" does not exist*

[image]

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare { get; set; } //! Added
}
// I want to create tables for two models below
public class ProductComparsion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }
}

public class ProductToCompare
{
    public int ProductComparsionId { get; set; }
    public ProductComparsion ProductComparsion { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }        
}
```

**AppDbContextModelProvider**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductComparsion>(typeBuiler =>
{
    typeBuiler.ToTable(nameof(AppDbContext.ProductsComparsion));
    typeBuiler.HasKey(z => z.Id);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductToCompare>(typeBuilder =>
{
    typeBuilder.HasKey(z => new { z.ProductId, z.ProductComparsionId });
    typeBuilder.ToTable(nameof(AppDbContext.ProductsToCompare));                
    typeBuilder.HasOne(z => z.ProductComparsion).WithMany(z => z.ProductsToCompare).HasForeignKey(z => z.ProductComparsionId);  
    typeBuilder.HasOne(z => z.Product).WithMany(z => z.ProductsToCompare).HasForeignKey(z => z.ProductId);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Probably because the tables were already part of the model. What changes did you make after you deleted the tables?

Comment: @phuzi I added 2 comments `//! Added` to code. I made this changes. And need to create tables `ProductComparsion`, `ProductToCompare`

Comment: So, `ProductsToCompare` is a new property on `Product` and `ProductComparsion`. I'm guessing that `ProductToCompare` is also a new entity. Is that correct? None of these changes required any change to the `ProductsComparsion` table.

Comment: @phuzi ProductToCompare is not new, but I think I know what to do. I deleted tables manually and EF don't know about it. Now I try to revert to the previous migration, but getting error when try to apply it: `relation "ProductsToCompare" does not exist`. Can't understand, why

Comment: Trying to revert to the previous migration is failing because it is failing trying to drop a table that doesn't exist. Because you manually dropped the table, you'll have to manually re-create it. Doing anything manually outside EF migrations is likely to end in tears as EF doesn't know what you did.